# $\mathbb Z/2$-orbifolds in Virasoro representations, CFTs, VOAs

Tags: rt.representation-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, vertex-algebras

Suppose that ${\rm Vir}_c$ is a rational [Virasoro algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virasoro_algebra) with central charge $c$.
Then ${\rm Vir}_c$ has finitely many irreducible modules $M_h$, parametrised by the highest weights $h$.
Furthermore the decomposition $M_i\otimes M_j = \sum_h N_{ij}^h M_h$
has a combinatorial description,
and the decomposition is usually referred to as the *fusion rules*.

> Suppose that a group $G$ acts on the representation $W$ of $V$.
>   How (and when) is the orbifold $W^G_{\rm orb}$ defined?

Following the book Conformal Field Theory (CFT) by Di-Francesco--Mathieu--Senechal:
An example of a CFT is a representation $W = \sum M_h\otimes \overline{M_{h'}}$
of ${\rm Vir}_c\otimes\overline{{\rm Vir}_c}$.
The partition function $Z$ is the corresponding sum of characters $\sum \chi_h\otimes\overline{\chi_{h'}}$.
The orbifold $Z^{\langle G\rangle}_{\mathop{orb}}$ is defined as $\frac{1}{\lvert G\rvert}\sum_{(a,b)}Z_{a,b}$,
where $(a,b)$ is a commuting pair of elements from $G$
and $Z_{a,b}$ is the partition function of a conformal field theory with suitably twisted boundary conditions.
A representation is modular if its partition function is invariant under the action of $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$.
Generally, orbifolding seems to be described as a method of getting a modular representation from another modular representation.
Is there instead a combinatorial way to find orbifolds,
or a description of the method on the modules?

On the other hand,
suppose that group $G$ acts on a VOA $V$.
Its 'orbifold' $V^G$ (in the papers I've seen)
is the set of $G$-fixed points in $V$.
A conformal VOA $V$ carries a representation of ${\rm Vir}_c$.
I've heard that $V$ describes the left-handed part of a CFT (i.e. only the modules $M_h\otimes 1$ in the chiral representation above).
Can the Virasoro-orbifolding be translated to VOAs?
(Or to any other representation of ${\rm Vir}_c$?)

It turns out from the fusion rules that the highest weights $H$ of ${\rm Vir}_c$ always admit a $\mathbb Z/2$-grading $t$
such that if $M_h$ is a constituent of $M_i\otimes M_j$ then $t(h) = t(i) + t(j)$.
Set $\tau(M_h) = (-1)^{t(h)}M_h$,
and set $W = \sum_{h\in H}M_h\otimes\overline{M_h}$.
The $\tau$-fixed module $\sum_{t(h)=0} M_h$
looks very different to the orbifold $W^{\langle\tau\rangle}_{\rm orb}$ of $W$:
possibly $W^{\langle\tau\rangle}_{\rm orb} = W$
(for $c = 1/2$)
or certain modules occur in $W^{\langle\tau\rangle}_{\rm orb}$ with multiplicity $2$
(for $c = 4/5$).
This is an example of an orbifolding I would like to understand.
From Miyamoto's q-alg/9710038, for example,
it looks like some of these $\mathbb Z/2$-orbifolds play cool roles in the VOAs.